# How to build a tower that reaches dozens of miles into space

Tags: science-based, construction

in the recent Star Wars: The Old Republic expansion Knights of the Fallen Empire, the planet of Zakuul, seat of the Eternal Empire, has a number of buildings that are so big that they're clearly visible from outer space as long pins on the globe, even when so far away that one can see the entire planet at once. Below is a picture of Zakuul with the towers clearly visible.

[image]

Here is another image of the towers with a spaceship for comparison. The tower you see here is the same as the tallest tower in the top image. if you zoom in on the orb, you can JUUUST about make out the Eternal Throne itself.

[image]

Obviously, on our current Earth with our current tech, such towers would be impossible. However, this is Star Wars. How would the inhabitants of the Galaxy Far Far Away build a tower like this?

Comment: They would build it like that.... by building it like that...

Comment: space fountain?

Comment: Magic, Star wars is  Fantasy not science fiction like most people believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antigravity. *Star Wars* technology clearly includes control of gravity, since people walk around normally in spaceships and stations (the Death Stars may be big enough to plausibly generate some gravity from their sheer mass, but nothing smaller is), and you can build arbitrarily tall buildings if you can turn off gravity locally.

Comment: The size of the planet could be a factor as well. I would think that, looking at the images OP provided, Zakuul is much smaller than Earth, so has less gravity to overcome.

Comment: They absolutely do have this technology, and it has a name! http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Repulsorlift

Answer (score 4):

In the real world, we do have the concept of the "orbital elevator" which is reliant on materials technology rather than antigravity (as one would think would be used in the Star Wars universe). Obviously, in a Star Wars universe, using something that neutralizes gravity itself may be the cheapest thing to do, but there is a theoretical possibility of building something which would connect what amounts to a geosynchronous orbital platform to a single point on the surface via an incredibly strong and light weight, gigantic cable. We do not have the technology to do this, but some research into carbon strands and other materials has taken place to see if a material light and strong enough could be built.

Comment: Space elevators, to work, must be long enough to reach past geosynchronous orbit.  For earth, that's an orbital radius of ~35,700km.  For comparison, the diameter of the earth itself is only ~12,700km.  The spires shown, though absurdly tall, are far too short.